Unifying cell size and extent of raster layers in QGIS
In ArcGIS Pro, when using many analysis tools that deal with or generate raster layers, you can set the cell size and extent to exactly match another layer. This allows for map algebra to be done between and among many layers which are all perfectly aligned.
Is there any way to do this in QGIS?

Align rasters? Prior to 3.34 this was available as a non-processing tool via the Raster menu.

I believe several raster processing tools offer this option by selecting a layer to base the extent off of, and setting the resolution. Might be a little more hands on than ArcGIS, but it's possible.

@BenW got it, Raster Tools -> Align Rasters
